# Replace character " in C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to replace the character " by a space in a string in C#.
But I have an issue when writing the function :

```
myString.Replace("""," ")
```

The first argument seems to be an issue.
Any idea

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Escape it:

```
myString.Replace("\""," ")
```

Comment: Or use the overload using characters: `string.Replace('"', ' ')`.

Answer (score 12):

Use the overload that accepts chars instead of strings

```
myString.Replace('"', ' ');
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the character by putting \ before it:

```
myString=myString.Replace("\""," ");
```

or user this:

```
 myString=myString.Replace('"',' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape it.

You can use regular strings:

```
myString.Replace("\""," ")
```

or [verbatim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [strings](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/harishankar2005/verbatim_literals11262005010742AM/verbatim_literals.aspx):

```
myString.Replace(@""""," ")
```